# In VB.Net MVC, how can I pass a list to the view and display it using the Model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am populating a list of strings in VB and wanting to display its results in the View.  I am returning the list to the view like this:

```
Dim nameList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

Function AddName(theName As String) As ActionResult
    nameList.Add(theName)
    Return View(nameList)
End Function
```

However, I can not seem to find examples of how to process this list as part of the Model and display it using ASP.  My view is a .vbhtml file, and the syntax feels quite different to do this as opposed to a .cshtml file.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you are already handing the model data to the view. You need to inform the view of the model type to use in the first line of the view.

As an example, you can use a `For Each` loop to display the data:

```
@ModelType System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)
<div>
    <ul>
        @For Each s In Model
            @<li>
                @s
            </li>
        Next
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for in regards to displaying my list!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't retain the nameList variable across postbacks; it will always be only one variable.  If you stored it in session or database, loaded it from there, it would work:

```
Function AddName(theName As String) As ActionResult
    Dim nameList As List(Of String) = CType(HttpContext.Session("NAME_LIST"), List(Of String))

    If (nameList is Nothing) Then
       nameList = new List(Of String)
    End If

    nameList.Add(theName)

    HttpContext.Session("NAME_LIST") = nameList

    Return View(nameList)
End Function
```

Forgive my VB as it's a little rusty, hopefully the syntax is close enough.  Everytime you add something, it gets added to the list stored in session; the very first time, the list will be null because it wasn't created in session yet, but the null check creates an empty list and the first item will be added OK.  When session dies, the list dies, so you may need to incorporate a database.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian for your response.  I did not realize that this would be an issue, and your solution indeed solves that.  Between your and Markus' answer, I now have the functionality I desired.